# Full width Hover Navigation With Fixed Top

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sir/mam,
I am having trouble with my Navbar.I want it to be fixed at Top When scroll but the "Dropdown content" goes up when the nav get fixed at Top it Doesn't Go along with nav bar. I want it to go along with navbar.

```css
.dropbtn {
background-color: #006600;
color: #fff;
font-size: 15px;
padding:10px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #5f5;
    width:1024px;
    left:0;
    position: fixed;    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}
 #bgcl{
background: #006600;
width: 1024px;
}
.nav{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 1366;
z-index: 9999;
top:100px;
overflow: hidden;
 }
#page{
    height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="nav">
    <div id="bgcl" >
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><button class="dropbtn">Option 1</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <h1>full width Dropdown 1</h1>
      </div>
       </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><button class="dropbtn">Option 1</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <h1>full width Dropdown 2</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Copied The Code From W3schools And did a lil change because the dropdown size were small And i want it to be wider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If I understand well. You must to use Javascript to fixed the navbar in the top, when is scroll it. I use the var topPos to know the constant height of the scroll and when is highter than 100 add the class navbarTop that apply new styles to the navbar like position: fixed; and set the top: 0; to push the navbar to the top of the page.

```js
 var scrollTop = $(".nav");
 
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();
  
     if (topPos > 100) {
      $(scrollTop).addClass("navbarTop");

    } else{
     $(scrollTop).removeClass("navbarTop");
    }
 });
```

```css
.dropbtn {
background-color: #006600;
color: #fff;
font-size: 15px;
padding:10px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #5f5;
    width:1024px;
    left:0;
    position: fixed;    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;    
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}
 #bgcl{
background: #006600;
width: 1024px;
}
.nav{
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 1366;
z-index: 9999;
top:100px;
overflow: hidden;


 }
#page{
    height: 1500px;
}

.navbarTop{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div class="nav">
    <div id="bgcl" >
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><button class="dropbtn">Option 1</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <h1>full width Dropdown 1</h1>
      </div>
       </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"><button class="dropbtn">Option 1</button></a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
      <h1>full width Dropdown 2</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I already have this.I want the content to scroll up along with navbar.when you hover on "option 1" its Dropdown content appear but when You scroll The dropdown content remains at the position until navbar goes to top and fixed then the dropdown content move. I want Both to go along

Answer (score 0):

I believe your #nav div should have a fixed position too.

```
.nav{
   position: fixed;
...
```

Is that what you were looking for as a result?

Comment: Yes. In Jquery..But the dropdown content doesn't Go along with navbar when scroll. i want it to go up with navbar.[https://navbharattimes.indiatimes.com] see they have the same navigation i want too